# An example where great-circle distance gives a different answer than $L_2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given three 3D vectors A B C, when does great-circle distance tell us A and B are closer, but $L_2$ norm tells us A and C are closer?

Also, any geometric intuition would be great.

Comment: Do all three vectors have the same length? If not, how is great-circle distance defined?

Comment: Yes all unit vecs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such example can be found. Consider that if we're on the unit circle, the great-circle distance between unit vectors $U$, $V$ is just the angle between them in radians: $$0 \leq d_{\bigodot}(U, V) = \theta(U, V) \leq \pi.$$

The $L^2$-distance between them, $d_{L^2}(U, V) = \| U - V \|$,  can be found using elementary trig as $$0 \leq d_{L^2}(U, V) = 2 \sin \left( \frac{\theta(U, V)}{2} \right) = 2\sin \left( \frac{d_{\bigodot}(U, V)}{2} \right) \leq 2.$$

On  the interval $[0, \pi]$, the function $f(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta/2)$ is an increasing bijection onto its image $[0, 2]$,  so if $d(A, B) > d(A, C)$ in one metric, it's also bigger in the other metric as well. In fact, [these metrics are strongly equivalent,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics) since $$\|U - V \| \leq \theta(U, V) \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \|U - V\|$$ for all unit vectors $U, V \in S^2$ *(i.e. $x \leq 2 \arcsin(x/2) \leq \pi x/2$ for all $x \in [0, 2]$)*.

[image: The metric equivalence above given as a graph.]